# Как задать прозрачность заднего фона без прозрачности содержимого?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать задний фон полупрозрачным без прозрачности инпутов кнопки и текста?

```
<form class="form_phone">
    <p style="font-size: 25px;">Узнайте цену сейчас</p>
    <input class="form_phone_input" type="phone" name="phone" required="" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон">
    <button class="form_phone_btn">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.form_phone
{
    padding: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px; 
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    width: 340px;
    float: left;
}
.form_phone_input
{
    width: 260px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block; 
}
.form_phone_btn
{
    width: 260px;
    height: 60px;
    outline-style: none;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 0px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.form_phone_btn:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

задать цвет в формате rgba

```
 .form_phone {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, простое решение,к которое я к сожалению не додумался(